# Dynamic ng-click does not call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wish to make a dynamic table in AngularJS, but the problem is `ng-click` does not call the function.

- Here is the fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tep78g6w/2/)
- Here is the code :

General template :

```
<div class="box">
    <dynamic-table></dynamic-table>
</div>
```

Directive template :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-bind="column.label"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="content in data">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <!-- Problem is here (column[function] displays 'displayCategory') -->
        <a href ng-click="column[function]()">{{ content[column.field] }}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Directive code :

```
app.directive('dynamicTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'/template/Directive/dynamic-table.html',
        scope: true,
        link: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.updateCategory = function() {
                console.log("WOW");
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

When I display : `column[function]`, it shows `updateCategory`. I don't understand why when I click on it, the function is not launched...

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because column[function] returns a string, not a reference to the function itself. You should call the function directly, like:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <!-- Problem is here (column[function] displays 'displayCategory') -->
    <a href ng-click="updateCategory (column)">{{ column.field }}</a>
</td>
```

and inside the directive to have something like:

```
 controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.updateCategory = function(columnData) {
            console.log(columnData.field);
        };
    }]
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but I must keep a dynamic ng-click, that's why I can't call it directly ! It could call the function updateCategory(), or updatePorudct(), or payBill(). I will add those functions inside the controller later.

Comment: Then you can try to do smth like $scope[column[function]], but this is not the best solution. I would go with a function called performAction with a parameter to identify which action you have to perform and execute the needed code based on that.

Comment: Oh, you mean, like doing a switch case in that function ? I like this idea, thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, glad I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Check demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tep78g6w/29/).

First of all, you link function declaration is not correct:

```
link: ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.updateCategory = function() {
        console.log("WOW");
    };
}]
```

It is the format of `controller` function. Change it to:

```
link: function($scope) { ... }
```

**Angular will do the injection for you.**

Secondly, specify a dispatcher function on the scope. Inside the dispatcher, determine which function to call:

```
$scope.dispatcher = function (column) {
    var fn = column.function;
    fn && angular.isFunction($scope[fn]) && $scope[fn]();
};
```

And specify `ng-click="dispatcher(column)"` in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Please see this fiddle as maybe it will suit your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/tep78g6w/45/

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.updateCategory = function() {
        console.log("WOW");
    };

    scope.doSomething = function(func) {
        var test = scope.$eval(func);
            if(test)
                 test();
            }
     }
}
```

Also, link function has parameters that are sent to it, this is not a place to use DI. Please see in the fiddle the correct approach. As far as the dynamically calling the function, I went with different approach and it works. The approach you took is not going to work because you need a way for the string to be a function, it needs to have a reference to a function.